# data is not filtered by the searchbar

Tags: json, swift, uisearchbar

I am trying to filter my fetched JSON data using a searchbar. However, when I type something into the searchbar it does nothing. Data is still in the same place and it is not filtered, whereas it should be dynamically filtered while I am typing something into the searchbar.

The code below shows my TableViewController as well as the function for fetching JSON data into my array. It is then filtered using a searchbar and whenever the data's name is matching the condition in the search bar it is then added to the second array called 'filteredExercise'.

```
import UIKit

class ExerciseTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

var fetchedExercise = [Exercise]()
var filteredExercise = [Exercise]()
var inSearchMode = false

@IBOutlet var searchBar: UITableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchBar.delegate = self

    parseData()

}


func parseData() {

    fetchedExercise.removeAll()

    let urlPath = "https://wger.de/api/v2/exercise/?format=json&language=2&status=2&limit=200"
    let url = URL(string: urlPath)!

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print("Error while parsing JSON")
        }
        else {

            do {
                if let data = data,
                    let fetchedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableLeaves) as? [String:Any],
                    let exercises = fetchedData["results"] as? [[String: Any]] {


                    for eachExercise in exercises {
                        if eachExercise["license_author"] as! String == "wger.de" {
                            let name = eachExercise["name"] as! String
                            let description = eachExercise["description"] as! String
                            let id = eachExercise["id"] as! Int

                            self.fetchedExercise.append(Exercise(name: name, description: description, id: id))
                        }
                    }


                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
            catch {
                print("Error while parsing data.")
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}



// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows

    if inSearchMode {

        return filteredExercise.count
    }

    return fetchedExercise.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ExerciseCell", for: indexPath) as? ExerciseCell {

        let exercise: Exercise!

        if inSearchMode {

            exercise = filteredExercise[indexPath.row]
            cell.configureCell(exercise: exercise)

        } else {

            exercise = fetchedExercise[indexPath.row]
            cell.configureCell(exercise: exercise)
        }

        return cell

    } else {

        return UITableViewCell()
    }


}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    var exercise: Exercise!

    exercise = fetchedExercise[indexPath.row]

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "exerciseDetailVC", sender: exercise)
}


func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {

        inSearchMode = false
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    } else {

        inSearchMode = true

        let lower = searchBar.text!.lowercased()

        filteredExercise = fetchedExercise.filter({$0.name.range(of: lower) != nil})
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have an error in?

```
@IBOutlet var searchBar: UITableView!
```

I think it should be type of UISearchBarController.

Comment: Oh that's true. I have changed it to '@IBOutlet var searchBar: UISearchBar!' but it still does not solve an issue.

Comment: If you haven't, you'll probably need to reconnect the outlet instead of just change the text. Once you alter an IBOutlet connection text it disconnects. It looks like your delegate is set too, but if it weren't that could also be an issue. You can hook it (the delegate) up through storyboards as well.

Comment: Please check the answer as accepter if it helped to you

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have finally figured out what is wrong with it.

Basically first of all I had incorrect type for my searchBar due to the Xcode bug and I did not see that.
Then I had to connect my IBOutlet to the storyboard as well because it was not done.
Finally I started getting wrong results while filtering through the data and it was because I have been filtering through results using a lowercased() function, whereas all my data is capitalized.